# fadeout row after delete with ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have ajax to delete per `row`. i have table and colomn with `action` to delete

this my ajax

```js
//hapus detail
            function deleteDetail(id_po_req_detail) {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                $(".loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "po_req/po_req_crud.php",
                    data: {id_po_req_detail: id_po_req_detail, type: "delete_detail"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".loader").hide();
                            tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                            tr.remove();            
                        }); 
                        }, 300);
                    }
                });
            }
```

```html
<table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.</th>
                                        <th>Model</th>
                                        <th>Ukuran</th>
                                        <th>Jumlah</th>
                                        <th>Keterangan</th>
                                        <th>Aksi</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" onclick=" if(confirm('Hapus detail ?')) deleteDetail(1);">Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" onclick=" if(confirm('Hapus detail ?')) deleteDetail(2);">Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" onclick=" if(confirm('Hapus detail ?')) deleteDetail(3);">Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```

how to fadeout with jquery if i click delete button ?thanks so much ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of `$(this) will not` work in your `function deleteDetail(id_po_req_detail)` you have to `pass this as parameter` then and then only `$(parameter)` works. SO

pass second parameter like

`deleteDetail(1,this);`

`deleteDetail(2,this);`

`deleteDetail(3,this);`

Receive that parameter in your function definition like below and change your function like below

```
function deleteDetail(id_po_req_detail,ele) {
                var tr = $(ele).closest('tr');
                $(".loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "po_req/po_req_crud.php",
                    data: {id_po_req_detail: id_po_req_detail, type: "delete_detail"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".loader").hide();
                            tr.fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                              tr.remove();            
                            }); 
                        }, 300);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Comment: thanks Rakesh. but i create table by jquery. so the button delete like this `onClick=\" if(confirm('Hapus detail ?')) deleteDetail(" + id_po_req_detail + ");\"` how to i insert `this` ?

Comment: write your full code. How you create table by jQuery ?

Comment: You can write like `onclick=\" if (confirm('Hapus detail ?'))deleteDetail("+id_po_req_detail+", this);\"`

Comment: yeah, this work thanks guys. how do fadein if row inserted like fadeout ?

Comment: You can do like `var tr = "<tr><td>1</td><td>Zn 233</td><td>Small</td><td>2</td><td>dewd</td><td> <a href=\"#\" onclick=\" if (confirm('Hapus detail ?'))deleteDetail(" + id_po_req_detail + ", this);\">Hapus</a></td></tr>";
        $(tr).hide().appendTo('table').fadeIn(2000);`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then you must use real power of it. First bootstrap the click event, inline click event is highly avoidable.

```js
//hapus detail

$(document).on('click','.delete-button',function(event){
  
  console.log($(this).data('id'))
  
  if(!confirm('Hapus detail ?'))
    return false;
  
   var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                $(".loader").show();
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                     dataType: "json",
                    url: "po_req/po_req_crud.php",
                    data: {id_po_req_detail: $(this).data('id'), type: "delete_detail"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $(".loader").hide();
                            tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                            tr.remove();            
                        }); 
                        }, 300);
                    }
                });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No.</th>
                                        <th>Model</th>
                                        <th>Ukuran</th>
                                        <th>Jumlah</th>
                                        <th>Keterangan</th>
                                        <th>Aksi</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" class='delete-button' data-id='1'>Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" class='delete-button' data-id='2'>Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Zn 233</td>
                                    <td>Small</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>dewd</td>
                                    <td> <a href="#" class='delete-button' data-id='3' >Hapus</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
```